# What's the difference between so, and because in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> We live near the sea because we like to go to the beach every day.

There's a mistake in this sentence, that I have to correct it, so my first try is 
 to go ==> going. 
  but, my friend told me that I was wrong, it should be because ==> so. So I don't know whether I'm right or my friend is right. What's the correct answer for this?

Comment: I don't see any mistake in the original sentence. Is it taken from a longer paragraph? Changing "because" to "so" would reverse the causal relationship, which might make sense with additional context.

Comment: While _because_ states a reason, _so_ is followed by a result. I don't think your friend's right. With so, it should be, 'We live near the sea so **we could go** to the beach every day.' Using _going_ might be an improvement but still I don't see a problem with _like to go_.

Comment: to go vs going - they both sound fine to me.  I guess using going could possibly mean you like the actual act of traveling to the beach as opposed to the beach itself, but honestly, from context, it is obvious that this is not the intention.  If you want to use "so", it needs further help.  It would have to be "We live near the sea so that we can go to the beach everyday."  So that / in order to type construct.  "Because" is clearer here.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence as written. The difference is that, if you change "because" to "so" you change the meaning of the sentence.

> Because we like to go to the beach every day, we chose to live near the coast.
>
> Because we live near the coast, we enjoy going to the beach every day.

I couldn't say which is the "right" answer until you decide which of these sentences your example is *supposed* to mean.